# How to get authors in links?

Tags: php, regex, string, text

I am trying to get the names `Pucheu_M`, `Romero_C`, `Bellini_M` and `Aguilar_J` in

```
http://arxiv.org/find/gr-qc/1/au:+Pucheu_M/0/1/0/all/0/1
http://arxiv.org/find/gr-qc/1/au:+Romero_C/0/1/0/all/0/1
http://arxiv.org/find/gr-qc/1/au:+Bellini_M/0/1/0/all/0/1
http://arxiv.org/find/gr-qc/1/au:+Aguilar_J/0/1/0/all/0/1
```

This is what I tried:

```
/"au:+"([^/]+)/?$
```

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJ4tC9/1).

However no result is found. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex must be like below.

- Escape the `+` symbol.
- Use a different php delimiter.
- Put `/` and `$` inside a group delimited by `|`. Because think your input won't contain an end of the line immediately next to `/` symbol.
- Finally get the string you want from group index 1.

Regex:

```
'~/au:\+([^/]+)(?:/|$)~'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kJ4tC9/2)

Comment: I can be wrong, but the regex can go even shorter - `\+([\w_]+)`. Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/kJ4tC9/7

Comment: what if the  word contain non-word chars?

Comment: Well, since none of the examples provided had any characters that weren't non-word chars I assumed they won't be used. Plus its an URL, so it's rather plain text that is matched here. Also one can add missing characters to `[ ... ]` and this regex would still work.